# C#. Fastest Regex to match any string

Tags: c#, regex

Quite simple. What's the fastest regex that will return true for any input?

For context I must use a function that takes a regex filter and I want to know what will make it match everything the most quickly.

Comment: have you even thought about this? I sounds as useful as a chocolate teapot.

Comment: ...not using a regex?

Comment: What real world scenario prompted this question?

Comment: are you entering questions to test the community response time or to make your friend answer then you vote him and he grows reputation!? :-P

Comment: @Matt: Depending on the tea, though, could be tasty ... as long as you had a bigger bowl to put the whole thing in.

Comment: @Matt: well, if the teapot is really really thick...... :P

Comment: "why the down votes?" - I see only one down vote which has been nullified with a +3 rep boost by an upvote.

Comment: If you care about speed in the case of a regex filter that always returns true, you should not run a regex in that case. For example, you could pass in a null value to your filter function, and code it to skip the check when the regex is null. Not running a regex is always going to be faster than running any regex, if speed matters that much.

Comment: @Matt - I'm going to borrow your teapot metaphor, probably sometime today :)

Comment: @Joel Mueller, valid points indeed but suppose the function you were calling was in third party code.  Quite a few people have suggested empty string, I'll probably go with that.

Comment: @Tim be my guest! I borrowed it from someone else :)

Comment: You might need this when you have a situation where you want to match, say, a filename specified in a configuration file, but in (only) certain cases, you can match any file.  So when you can match any file, you may as well enter the pattern that matches fastest.  (Though I'm sure the difference is in microseconds.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class FastestRegex
{
    public static readonly Regex RE = new Regex("", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Comment: Just a note for the heck of it, but you might as well just use the .NET internal Regex cache and stick to the static functions on Regex

Comment: @LorenVS: That depends on how many regexes you're creating and what size you've set for the regex cache.  But you **know** this one is going to be reused, so why not cache it manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it would have to be something like

```
.*?
```

which would check for a match with any character, but because of the lazy operator, would match no string at all.  I imagine that it would return before even checking the first character.  This is assuming that the empty string doesn't return true for all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that either the empty string, `""`, or the start-of-input, `"^"`, would result in the fastest (positive) match for any string.

You should try it yourself though: running a few quick tests, the pattern `"^"` is usually faster than `""` on Oracle's 1.6 JRE, but on Mono 2.4, it's the other way around. In both cases, `.*?` is *way* slower.

But again: test things on your own system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fastest regex that never runs a regex. Therefore the fastest regex is the one that actually runs. `/[\S\s]?/` or, I'm guessing this is faster `/.?/s`

Addon - Interresting though `/^/` benched fractionally faster in perl looped 30 million times. However, pre-compiling all the regex' first slows them all down by a factor of 5. Go figure. Maybe because its too simple an expression.